# 301 redirect from one subdomain.domain1.com to domain2.com

Tags: .htaccess, 301-redirect

Title says it all really, I want to be able to 301 redirect from `subdomain.domain1.com` to `domain2.com`.

I have full access to the servers and have tried various things using `.htaccess` but have had no success.

The reason for this is because I have a site that was hosted on a subdomain but has since moved to its own domain and I want to redirect any requests to the right place. How would one go about achieving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be just a case of putting something like the following in

```
redirect 301 /index.htm http://domain2.com/index.htm
```

Though you can also do stuff with mod rewrite to catch all requests.

Answer (score 0):

In your httpd.conf file, inside the vhost that serves subdomain.domain1.com:

`Redirect Permanent / http://domain2.com/`